# Android : getting soft keyboard height

Tags: android, keyboard

As the title, I just want to get the keyboard height.

Since there are so many resolution on Android phones, it is hard to handle.

So Is there any API for that?

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your Activity:

```
 iSoftkeyboardHeight = viewMain.getHeight(); // viewMain - root view of your activity

 int y = iSoftkeyboardHeight - 2;
 int x = 10;
 int counter = 0;
 int height = y;
 int iSoftkeyboardHeightNow = 0;
 Instrumentation instrumentation = new Instrumentation();
 while( true)
  {
    final MotionEvent m = MotionEvent.obtain(  SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0);
    final MotionEvent m1 = MotionEvent.obtain( SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,   x, y, 0);
    boolean ePointerOnSoftkeyboard = false;

    try
      {
        instrumentation.sendPointerSync(m);
        instrumentation.sendPointerSync(m1);
      }
     catch (SecurityException e)
      {
         ePointerOnSoftkeyboard = true;
      }
    if( !ePointerOnSoftkeyboard)
      {
        if( y == height)
          {
            if( counter++ < 100)
              {
                Thread.yield();
                continue;
              }
          }
         else
          if( y > 0)
            iSoftkeyboardHeightNow = iSoftkeyboardHeight - y;
        break;
      }
    y--;
    m.recycle();
    m1.recycle();
  }
 if( iSoftkeyboardHeightNow > 0)  iSoftkeyboardHeight = iSoftkeyboardHeightNow;
  else iSoftkeyboardHeight = 0;

 // now use iSoftkeyboardHeight
```

Comment: I tried this code after showing the keyboard and it crashes the app.