# [Android]How to get soft keyboard height. (Except the suggestions)

Tags: android, keyboard

First, it's not a simple question like [this quest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755603/android-getting-soft-keyboard-height) or [this quest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286836/get-soft-keyboard-height-in-fragment).

I have to get soft keyboard height in my project. I used to get device screen height and subtraction it by out app root view height. However, it work correctly until my test using keyboard suggestion. Unfortunately for me, my solution did not right in this case. The number I got alway bigger than the soft keyboard height. I tried to google but fail.

Here's my picture:
[image]